# Creating a make file

Tags: c, makefile

How would one create a make file for running e.g. xml parser with the following command line command

```
gcc source.c -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 -o output
```

I use this to include libxml when compiling using the command line.

How would this be made using a make file instead of the command line usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SOURCES:=source.c
OBJECTS:=$(SOURCES:%.c=%.o)
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -Wall -I/usr/include/libxml2
LD=gcc
LDFLAGS=
LIBS=-lxml2
TARGET:=output



all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
        $(LD) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

depend:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $(SOURCES) > .depend

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET) 

.depend: depend

include .depend
```

You can use this as a template, then add to/modify SOURCES, TARGET, CFLAGS, LDFLAGS and LIBS. Makefiles require TABs for indentation - so you'll need to fix the spaces if you copy-paste this.

Comment: Note that the command lines (the $(CC) and $(LD) lines) *must* start with a tab character, not spaces.

Comment: @Helium3: Enables most compiler warnings - you should make that a habit it'll tell you about a lot of common issues.

Comment: Simple Question here. What kind of file is a make file? just a plain .c file?

Comment: Also. is it 1 tab or two before e.g. $(LD) ?

Comment: @Helium3: A makefile is just a plain text file. A line starting with a tab is interpreted as a command; anything after the first tab is passed to the shell (after variable substitution and with the exclusion of a small number of control characters at the beginning of the command, such as @, -, +).

Comment: Thanks. So if I make this make file, will it compile the source file and then I can just run my main as usual and when it calls functions from the source file which used in the make file, it will run as usual? All I want to do is run my code, and make it compile the libxml stuff without me needing to pass it as a command line flag or whatever its called.

Comment: @Helium3: Yes. A Makefile does exactly that. Make the file, run make, and verify that the commands it executes match what you would manually do.

Answer (score 0):

In its simpliest form:

```
output: source.c
    gcc source.c -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 -o output
```

now you can say either `make output` of `make` and get `output` built.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow yourself to have the output file be the same name as the source (without .c suffix), you can just do:

```
CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/include/libxml2
LDFLAGS = -lxml2
```

With just those two lines in your makefile,

```
make source
```

will look for source.c and generate the executable named 'source' with the appropriate flags.